# How can we use HTTP over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)?

Tags: android, http, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a way to send HTTP messages (GET, POST, etc) from BLE central(client) to BLE Peripheral(Server)? Currently, I am sending plain text using GATT protocol. Since an HTTP server already running inside my Peripheral, I would rather utilize HTTP protocol. Somebody suggested me to use HPS(HTTP Proxy Service) over BLE to do this job. But I really don't have any idea about HPS.

Is there any other way to send HTTP messages from Client to Server over BLE? 
Can anybody tell me how this can be done? or Is there any other way to send HTTP over BLE.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I had to look up what HPS was..  "HTTP Proxy Service".  I guess that's the best way to handle HTTP over GATT, but it seems like a bad idea.  If you have access to regular Bluetooth you might get better results with a serial connection.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Tim. I understand it is a bad idea using HTTP over GATT. However I am forced to use HTTP over BLE. Do you have any other suggestion through which I can achieve HTTP over BLE.?

Comment: HPS.  I think it's a bad idea, but people responsible for the BLE GATT specifications felt that HPS was a good addition, so it can't be as bad as I thought.  If there's a standard, then use it.  However, as I already said, if you don't have to use BLE and can use regular Bluetooth (as many devices have both), you can get a faster throughput with a serial-like connection ("Serial Port Profile" I think is what it's called) and you don't have to develop or find an HPS server.

Comment: I would throw in another thought. See it the other way around: BLE over HTTP. It might bring another view to the approach and might make things easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<edit>`
You asked if there were any *other* way than the standardised HPS to send HTTP messages over Bluetooth. From what I know you have one more standardised option.
`</edit>`
The only thing standardised is IPv6 over BLE, but it's far from well-supported. The problem with http is that it will be pretty inefficient due to long strings that need to be sent as headers.

`<edit>`

You can find the HPS service here: https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=308344.

If you really want to use HTTP over BLE but don't want to use any of the standardised ways, you could for example open up an L2CAP CoC and simply send the HTTP request in one direction and send back the HTTP response in one direction. That way you just replace TCP with L2CAP CoC.

`</edit>`

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Emil. I accept your answer completely.

Comment: Thanks. Please press the green accept button to the left then :)

Comment: Rats!! I was hoping to send some AJAX requests over BLE, but, since they are HTTP(S) ...

Comment: The HTTP Proxy Service allows the Bluetooth LE client which uses it to stipulate that HTTPS must be used by the proxy when executing the HTTP request.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with Emil's statement that IPv6 over Bluetooth is the only standardised option. I work for the Bluetooth SIG btw. The HTTP Proxy Service is a standard GATT service. You can download the specification here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

There are comments here to the effect that "HTTP over Bluetooth" is a bad idea but no elaboration as to what it is that is "bad". I think there may be some confusion about what's involved though and what the intended use of the HTTP Proxy Service is.

This GATT HTTP Proxy service must run on a device that has both a Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) stack and a TCP/IP stack. It has GATT characteristics that allow HTTP requests to be configured, by writing values to those characteristics. This includes HTTP header values. The expectation is that most such parameters will not change or at least not change frequently after they have initially been set. Devices acting as a client to the GATT HTTP Proxy Service then send data over HTTP and TCP/IP *indirectly*, via the GATT server. They do this by writing to the HTTP Entity Body characteristic.... typically a small value such as a sensor reading. An HTTP operation is then triggered by the GATT client device by writing a single byte to the HTTP control point characteristic (e.g. 1 to trigger an HTTP GET).

It's perhaps a misnomer to talk about HTTP over Bluetooth. That's not what's happening here. This is a three tier architecture, with very lightweight Bluetooth LE communication between (1) a Bluetooth device and a (2) dual technology Bluetooth and TCP/IP device, acting as a proxy, which then communicates the Bluetooth encoded request that it has configured within it, to a (3) remote HTTP server over TCP/IP.

As for the comments about using the serial port profile and the suggestion that this would offer performance advantages, this too is questionable. There's no detail on what is envisaged here but I assume the idea is that entire HTTP operations be formulated and sent over a Bluetooth BR/EDR connection using the serial port profile. Bluetooth BR/EDR runs at 2 mega symbols per second at the physical layer and by default, Bluetooth LE runs at 1 mega symbol per second. But since Bluetooth 5, released several years ago, Bluetooth LE also supports 2 mega symbols per second. Furthermore, due to the design of the HTTP Proxy Service, with fixed or rarely varying component parts of an HTTP request only needing to be configured once, you will probably find you're transferring less data when using HPS vs SPP. It all depends, of course but I think this is likely....

Hope this helps.

Comment: HPS can probably work out fine, but I guess it can be a bit overkill if you just want to send some data over BLE. But sure if you build a large system and need to integrate BLE devices into an existing HTTP infrastructure then yes it might be a good idea. How many implementations of HPS are there?

Comment: I interpreted the question as if there were any *other* way than HPS to send HTTP messages over BLE, since Shibin already mentioned HPS in the question.

Comment: If you want to send data to an HTTP server, your choices are to use the HTTP Proxy Service, IPv6 over Bluetooth LE or a proprietary solution. Not sure about "overkill". The device acting as proxy could be a Raspberry Pi Zero W for example. It looks like there are currently 334 products of various sorts using HPS. See the Advanced Search feature of https://launchstudio.bluetooth.com/Listings/Search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bluetooth gateway. Some Bluetooth gateways support Restful API to operator devices.